# Disable view from adjusting when in tethering mode

Tags: ios, iphone

I don't want my view being shift down and all adjusted because in tethering mode. is it possible to disable view being adjusted ?

Comment: Need More explanation.

Answer (score 0):

iOS won't let you stop the status bar from changing sizes.

The easiest way to handle this is to dynamically size your views.  You can do this by getting the view's current size (`self.view.bounds`) and status bar size (`CGRectGetHeight([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame)`) in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Alternatively, you can use auto-layout.  These approaches will also set you up for success in handling rotation.

You also can observe the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` if you prefer.

Finally, you could just hide the status bar entirely:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: YES withAnimation:YES];
```

But your users may not like that approach.